# Notepad++ - formatting text to achieve 3 columns of text separated with tabulators

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace

I would like to format a text in Notepad ++.
What I try to reach is to create 3 columns of text separated with the tabulators. I would like to do it with Find/Replace Function.
Lets say that you have a text like this one:

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
```

How can I make this outcome?

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
```

Any ideas? Very problematic case.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(\S+)\R(\S+)\R`
- Replace with: `$1\t$2\t`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : beginning of line
(\S+)       : group 1, 1 or more non space characters
\R          : any kind of linebreak
(\S+)       : group 2, 1 or more non space characters
\R          : any kind of linebreak
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1          : content of group 1
\t          : a tabulation, replace with a space depending on your need
$2          : content of group 2
\t          : a tabulation, replace with a space depending on your need
```

**Result for given example:**

```
A   B   C
D   E   F
G   H   I
```

To deal with sentences instead of letters:

- Find what: `^(.+)\R(.+)\R`
- Replace with: `$1\t$2\t`

**Sample file before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! what if I would have sentences instead of single letter? Is it possible to do?

Comment: @Matthew: Sure, replace `\S+` with `.+` and take care to NOT check `. matches newline`

Comment: I just checked, they both doesn't work, I feel sorry. It is not finding me anything, doesn't match. I am not sure about replace with field.

Comment: @Matthew:It works fine for me, see my edit.

Comment: right, it does work.
Nice one Mate! Thank you!

Comment: @Matthew: You're welcome, glad it helps.

Comment: @Matthew: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, see: https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: at a risk of being negatively flagged, this could be done very easily, by copying the text as CSV and doing this in Excel.

Comment: @Cricrazy: For me, no risks you'll be negatively flagged. You can post this as an answer whith the whole procedure to do the job.